# How do I add elevation data to a shapefile in the attributes table?

Tags: shapefile, dem, elevation

I'm using ArcGIS to create a DEM/DTM for a viewshed analysis. I have an existing DTM created from UK OS Terrain 5.

I'm attempting to add the elevation data to the UK OS Open Map shapefiles for buildings and woodland. The method to do this would be to add an extra field in the attributes table and assign the 8m/15m elevation to this field respectively. What field type/properties should the new field have?

Comment: This depends on what processing you intend for after you joined the attributes, as well as what DEM-data you have. Also, please state which software you're using.

Comment: Sounds like you want `fload` or `double`

Comment: @Tung never heard of a "fload" variable type before 

Comment: @Hornbydd: haha would be amazing if ArcGIS or any software showed that when OP actually clicked on selection menu